# Error compiling Eigen with PGI compiler

Tags: c++, eigen, pgi

I'm trying to compile code that includes headers for Eigen using PGI's C++ compiler but get the following error:

```
"/opt/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/arch/SSE/PacketMath.h", line 413:
          error: more than one instance of overloaded function "_mm_prefetch"
          matches the argument list:
            function "_mm_prefetch(const char *, int)"
            function "_mm_prefetch(const void *, _mm_hint)"
            argument types are: (const char *, _mm_hint)
  template<> EIGEN_STRONG_INLINE void prefetch<float>(const float*   addr) { _mm_prefetch((const char*)(addr), _MM_HINT_T0); }
                                                                             ^

"/opt/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/arch/SSE/PacketMath.h", line 414:
          error: more than one instance of overloaded function "_mm_prefetch"
          matches the argument list:
            function "_mm_prefetch(const char *, int)"
            function "_mm_prefetch(const void *, _mm_hint)"
            argument types are: (const char *, _mm_hint)
  template<> EIGEN_STRONG_INLINE void prefetch<double>(const double* addr) { _mm_prefetch((const char*)(addr), _MM_HINT_T0); }
                                                                             ^

"/opt/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/arch/SSE/PacketMath.h", line 415:
          error: more than one instance of overloaded function "_mm_prefetch"
          matches the argument list:
            function "_mm_prefetch(const char *, int)"
            function "_mm_prefetch(const void *, _mm_hint)"
            argument types are: (const char *, _mm_hint)
  template<> EIGEN_STRONG_INLINE void prefetch<int>(const int*       addr) { _mm_prefetch((const char*)(addr), _MM_HINT_T0); }
                                                                             ^

"/opt/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/arch/SSE/Complex.h", line 131: error:
          more than one instance of overloaded function "_mm_prefetch" matches
          the argument list:
            function "_mm_prefetch(const char *, int)"
            function "_mm_prefetch(const void *, _mm_hint)"
            argument types are: (const char *, _mm_hint)
  template<> EIGEN_STRONG_INLINE void prefetch<std::complex<float> >(const std::complex<float> *   addr) { _mm_prefetch((const char*)(addr), _MM_HINT_T0); }
                                                                                                           ^

"/opt/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/arch/SSE/Complex.h", line 343: error:
          more than one instance of overloaded function "_mm_prefetch" matches
          the argument list:
            function "_mm_prefetch(const char *, int)"
            function "_mm_prefetch(const void *, _mm_hint)"
            argument types are: (const char *, _mm_hint)
  template<> EIGEN_STRONG_INLINE void prefetch<std::complex<double> >(const std::complex<double> *   addr) { _mm_prefetch((const char*)(addr), _MM_HINT_T0); }
                                                                                                             ^

5 errors detected in the compilation of "/Users/wooden/CLionProjects/EigenTest/main.cpp".
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/EigenTest.dir/main.cpp.o] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/EigenTest.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I get the same error regardless of code being compiled as long as an Eigen header is included. More specifically, I'm including the following:

```
#include <Eigen/Eigen>
```

And try to compile a simple "Hello World" program. CMakeLists.txt is also barebones besides Eigen's directives.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(EigenTest)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

add_executable(EigenTest main.cpp)

find_package (Eigen3 3.3 REQUIRED NO_MODULE)
target_link_libraries (EigenTest Eigen3::Eigen)
```

I should note that I'm on macOS Sierra (10.12.6) and I've tried both v17.10 and v18.4 of PGI. No special flags are being used for compilation. The Eigen package installed is the most recent one on MacPorts (eigen3 3.3.4).

I've made non-trivial use of Eigen before and everything works fine with GCC. I've also made use of PGI's compilers before without issue. Reason I'm trying to make use of both at the same time is that I need to use OpenACC pragmas in certain parts of my code which uses Eigen.

Any help leading me to the right direction would be appreciated.

## Update 1

Casting `addr` to `const void*` instead of `const char*` at the error's aforementioned lines (or commenting said lines) on Eigen's source files, I don't get a compilation error anymore. I can get basic functionality from Eigen, but more complex code does not link successfully. The following error is produced:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:


"__ZN98_INTERNAL_76__Users_wooden_CLionProjects_MLProject_src_Classification_LogisticRegression_cpp_c51a32f316_mm_castpd_si128E7__m128d", referenced from:
      __ZN5Eigen8internal29general_matrix_vector_productIldNS0_22const_blas_data_mapperIdlLi1EEELi1ELb0EdNS2_IdlLi0EEELb0ELi0EE3runEllRKS3_RKS4_Pdld in LogisticRegression.cpp.o
      __ZN5Eigen8internal11palign_implILi1E7__m128dE3runERS2_RKS2_ in LogisticRegression.cpp.o
      __ZN5Eigen8internal6palignILi1E7__m128dEEvRT0_RKS3_ in LogisticRegression.cpp.o
  "__ZN98_INTERNAL_76__Users_wooden_CLionProjects_MLProject_src_Classification_LogisticRegression_cpp_c51a32f316_mm_castsi128_pdE7__m128i", referenced from:
      __ZN5Eigen8internal29general_matrix_vector_productIldNS0_22const_blas_data_mapperIdlLi1EEELi1ELb0EdNS2_IdlLi0EEELb0ELi0EE3runEllRKS3_RKS4_Pdld in LogisticRegression.cpp.o
      __ZN5Eigen8internal11palign_implILi1E7__m128dE3runERS2_RKS2_ in LogisticRegression.cpp.o
      __ZN5Eigen8internal4pexpI7__m128dEET_RKS3_ in LogisticRegression.cpp.o
      __ZN5Eigen8internal6palignILi1E7__m128dEEvRT0_RKS3_ in LogisticRegression.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
make[2]: *** [MLProject] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/MLProject.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

## Update 2

Using `-DEIGEN_DONT_VECTORIZE` as suggested by @chtz on comments, which disables Eigen's built-in vectorization, project code compiles, links and executes successfully. That creates a major issue however, since Eigen was used for its vectorized linear algebra implementations to begin with.

As for the compilation error, it may be related to PGI's support of the `_mm_castpd_si128` type according to @ggael.

All in all, it seems that Eigen compatibility with PGI's C++ compiler is partial at best.

Comment: By commenting lines 413-415 of SSE/PacketMath.h and 131, 343 of SSE/Complex.h in Eigen's source files I get successful compilation and execution of trivial code including Eigen headers. However, that presumably breaks some functionality and my project won't execute with PGI. Strangely enough it still works with GCC. Could it be a bug on Eigen that somehow doesn't affect GCC?

Comment: Instead of commenting the full lines, what about only commenting the calls to `_mm_prefetch` ?

Comment: You could also try replacing the calls by `_mm_prefetch((const void*)(addr), _MM_HINT_T0)`. What do you mean by "won't execute with PGI"? Immediate segfault? Infinite loop?

Comment: N.B.: PGI is not in [the list of supported compilers](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page#Compiler_support) -- so strictly this behavior is not a bug in Eigen. You may still be able to get everything to work with some local patches. I strongly recommend running the test-suite afterwards, though.

Comment: @ggael All commented lines are one-line function definitions, so I don't think that's going to make a difference. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: @chtz I should have been more specific. I get a linking error for undefined symbols. From what I can tell there might be missing definitions for certain functions I use on Eigen matrices/vectors, like exp(). By the way, casting to (const void*) produces the same error, which makes me think it's not produced by missing functionality due to commenting those five lines. I updated the question with the exact error. I did notice PGI is not supported officially, but I was hoping this behavior was a result of me doing something wrong. Might have to change my linear algebra lib to Armadillo now.

Comment: Looks like PGI is having trouble with `_mm_castpd_si128` that should compile to a no-op. I'm afraid the problem is on PGI's side.

Comment: You can also try compiling with `-DEIGEN_DONT_VECTORIZE` (i.e., disabling vectorization)

Comment: @chtz Gave this a go and managed to link and execute successfully. So, presumably the issue lies with Eigen's built-in vectorization. Unfortunately that's also the primary reason I was using Eigen, so it's a bit of a deal-breaker. Thanks though, now I can do some testing before replacing Eigen with another linear algebra library.

Comment: @ggael From what I gather that relates to the compilation error caused by casting to `const char*`, right? Even with the workaround, that also becomes a problem for portability. I'll leave the Q open for a bit longer in case there are any other suggestions, but it looks like there's not much I can do at this point besides replacing Eigen with something else.

Comment: This is a problem in PGI's `emmintrin.h` file where the definition of `_mm_castsi128_pd` is disabled in C++ mode.

Comment: I pushed a workaround: https://bitbucket.org/eigen/eigen/commits/836d2952e32e/, but PGI seems to be pretty bad at SSE register allocations.